# Marshalling of generic types in Jersey

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

I need to return to client list of few results and total count of results. I have to do it on several places with different entities so I would like to have a generic class with these two attributes:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class QueryResult<T> implements Serializable {
    private int count;
    private List<T> result;

    public QueryResult() {
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void setResult(List<T> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public List<T> getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

And the service:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public QueryResult<TestEntity> findAll(
    QueryResult<TestEntity> findAll = facade.findAllWithCount();
    return findAll;
}
```

Entity is not important:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class TestEntity implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

But this causes: `javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class test.TestEntity nor any of its super class is known to this context.`

Returning of just collection is easy but I don't know how to return my own generic type. I tried to use `GenericType` but without success - I think it's ment for collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation:

```
@XmlSeeAlso(TestEntity.class)
@XmlRootElement
public class QueryResult<T> implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Another possibility is to use `@XmlElementRefs`.

Comment: Ah yes :) But this works only if you don't have many entities and always want to return a list of this entity. If you want to use `QueryResult` for different result types, then this becomes impractical.

Answer (score 6):

After battling with this myself I discovered the answer is fairly simple.
In your service, return a built response of a GenericEntity (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html) typed accordingly. For example:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response findAll(){
    return Response.ok(new GenericEntity<TestEntity>(facade.findAllWithCount()){}).build();
}
```

See this post as to why you cannot simply return GenericEntity: [Jersey GenericEntity Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015970/jersey-genericentity-not-working)

A more complex solution could be to return the GenericEntity directly and create your own XmlAdapter (http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) to handle marshalling/unmarshalling. I've not tried this, though, so it's just a theory.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue. The problem occurs because of Java's type erasure.

My first approach was to generate a result class for each entity type:

```
public class Entity1Result extends QueryResult<Entity1> { ... }

public class Entity2Result extends QueryResult<Entity2> { ... }
```

I returned the generic `QueryResult<>` in my serivces only for built-in types like `QueryResult<String>`, or `QueryResult<Integer>`

But this was cumbersome, because I had a lot of entities. So my other approach was to use only JSON and I changed my result class to be non-generic and use an `Object` result field:

```
public class QueryResult {
   private Object result;
}
```

It works fine, Jersey is able to serialize everything I give it into JSON (Note: I don't know if it is important, but the `QueryResult` and all my entities still have `@Xml...` annotations. This works also for lists with own entity types.

If you have problems with collections, you can also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818327/jaxb-how-should-i-marshal-complex-nested-data-structures)