# Getting error A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList/List<java.lang.String> was not found

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

well this has been posted a lot of time here but no solution worked for me...
i can avoid this error by making a wrapper class but it only returned

`</stringWrapper>`

what am i doing wrong ?

StringWrapper class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class StringWrapper {
    public StringWrapper (){}

    List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

    public void add(String s){ 
        list.add(s);
    }
}
```

code :

```
     @Path("/xml")
     @GET
     @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
     public StringWrapper mystring(){
        StringWrapper thestring=new StringWrapper();
        thestring.add("a");
        thestring.add("a");
        return thestring;
     }
```

Java Rest webservice using Jersey.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909482/marshalling-of-generic-types-in-jersey

Comment: that solution isnt working !!

Comment: really? Even this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14645979/1235336 ?

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362197/java-program-statement-how-to-make-a-computer-class-having-a-list-of-printers

Comment: Please post an example of the XML document that you expect to be returned from this endpoint.  With that, we can use http://stackoverflow.com/a/15552881/1818625 to get you a proper set of annotations.

Answer (score 2):

You should add at least a getter in your StringWrapper. Without public attributes, there is nothing to serialize. So the output is correct. If you do not want a tag around the list of your strings, you can mark a single getter with @XmlValue.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class StringWrapper {
    public StringWrapper (){}

    List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

    public void add(String s) { list.add(s); }

    @XmlValue    
    public List<String> getData() { return list; }

}
```

Comment: or maybe @XmlElement on the getter method, am I wrong?