# Java Program Statement : How to make a computer class having a list of printers available to it

Tags: java, collections

Java Problem Statement : How to make a computer class having a list of printers available to it.
I want to have a Computer class (something like this) which fullfills the problem statement

```
public class Computers{


   String computername;

   //printerlist
   public static ArrayList<String> printers=new ArrayList<String>();

   // computername-Printerlist
   public Map<String,ArrayList<String>> printerDB=newHashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();


    public Computers(String computername){

    this.computername=computername;

    // now what to put here so that each computer having a 
    // different computer name will have a list of printers available to it>

    }


}
```

Example:

Computername -- List of Printers

HP -- Hp Printer,  Samsung , Canon .

Comment: what exactly do you want?
also this statement : this.computername=computername; makes no sense.

Comment: I agree with tejas - it's hard to understand what you actually want here.  Your `Computer` class already has a "list of printers" available to it - the `printers` field.  Are you asking how this can be populated in the constructor?  Are you asking how other classes can query this field?  Are you asking about some other meaning of "have a list available to it"?  I don't really get what you want help with.

Comment: yes..how can a computer name"Apple" have its own list of printers , a computer name"HP" has its own list of printers...
see BaadShaah's answer below ...he is close but is not replying now..
bdw `this.computername=computername` ..makes sense !!

Answer (score 3):

First, lets define a Printer class.

```
package com.ggl.modeltest;

public class Printer {

    private String companyName;
    private String printerName;

    public Printer(String companyName, String printerName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.printerName = printerName;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public String getPrinterName() {
        return printerName;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((companyName == null) ? 0 : companyName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((printerName == null) ? 0 : printerName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Printer other = (Printer) obj;
        if (companyName == null) {
            if (other.companyName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!companyName.equals(other.companyName))
            return false;
        if (printerName == null) {
            if (other.printerName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!printerName.equals(other.printerName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public Printer copy() {
        return new Printer(companyName, printerName);
    }

}
```

This class has a constructor to define the values, and two getter methods to retrieve the values.  Once you create an instance of this class, you can't change it.

These types of non modifiable classes make debugging simpler.

The hashCode and equals methods look pretty scary.  I had Eclipse generate those methods for me.  The reason that we override these methods is that we're going to use them in the `Computer` class.

So now, we define the `Computer` class.

```
package com.ggl.modeltest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Computer {

    private List<Printer>   printerNames;

    private String          computerName;

    public Computer(String computerName) {
        this.computerName = computerName;
        this.printerNames = new ArrayList<Printer>();
    }

    public void addPrinter(Printer printerName) {
        this.printerNames.add(printerName);
    }

    public void removePrinter(Printer printerName) {
        for (int i = printerNames.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (printerNames.get(i).equals(printerName)) {
                printerNames.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Printer> getPrinterNames() {
        return printerNames;
    }

    public String getComputerName() {
        return computerName;
    }

}
```

The constructor takes the name of the computer.  Once an instance is constructed, there's no way to change the name of the computer.

Printers are added to and removed from a computer.  Two methods have been defined to add a printer to the computer, and remove a printer from a computer.

The remove method removes all instances of the printer from the `List`, in case more than one was entered.

The method that gets the printer list returns an instance of the `List`.  The calling program can change the contents of this List.  If you want to make sure that the calling program can't change the contents of the list, you make a deep copy of the `List`.

To make a deep copy, you write a copy method for the `Printer` class.

```
public Printer copy() {
    return new Printer(companyName, printerName);
}
```

Since strings are unchangeable, we don't have to make a copy of the strings.  If we had changeable values, we would have to make a copy of them as well.  That's why this is called a deep copy.  It can be difficult to get everything copied correctly the first time.  That's what testing is for.

Then you call this copy method in a loop in the `getPrinterNames` method of the `Computer` class.

```
public List<Printer> getPrinterNames() {
    List<Printer> list = new ArrayList<Printer>();

    for (Printer printer : printerNames) {
        list.add(printer.copy());
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: okay seems like THE good answer,but cant understand the "hash" and "equals" method...
Also the question uses `ArrayList<String>` and not `List<Object>` ..you might wanna give a thought about it...

Comment: @Altair Rules:  The hash method generates a somewhat unique number for a combination of company name and printer name.  You can use any algorithm you want.  The idea is to come up with as unique a set of numbers as you can for the combination of company name and printer name.  The equals method determines if two instances of Printer are equal.  Most of the code checks that the instances are Printer instances and not null.  I created a Printer class because of a comment in one of the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Create your Computer class and in the Computers class maintain computer objects list.
Computer class looks like this .

```
public class Computer{
   private  String computername;

   private ArrayList<String> printernames;

    public Computers(String computername,List<String> printernames){
    this.computername=computername;
    this.printernames=printernames;
    }

    //setters //gettters //


}
```

**Usage :**

```
String compname ="Apple";
List<String> printernames = new Arraylist<String>();
printernames.add("AplrPrinter1");
printernames.add("AplrPrinter2");
printernames.add("AplrPrinter3");
Computers comp = new Computers(compname,printernames);
```

Comment: this.computername=name; << "name" ??

Comment: @user2416728 sorry a typo.Edited.

Comment: So better is to create a class Printer and add properties to it.Pure OOP :) like printer name,company,paper..etc

Comment: would those printers only be available to computer name "Apple" ?..or every computer object can access those printers ??

Comment: hmm i am not getting...
only computer nameed "Apple" should have access to those printers...
will your code do this thing ??

Comment: the constructor should not have `List<String>` .. it should be added in a different method ..

Comment: @user2416728 - what exactly do you mean by "have access to" the printers, in your earlier question?  Do you want to define a particular subclass of `Printer`, which cannot be used at all by other classes?  Do you mean that certain instances of the Printer class are out of scope for all other computers?  Or do you mean some other runtime-specific means of restricting access?

Comment: a computer name "Apple" must have its own list of printers , a computer name"HP" must have its own separate list of printers...
All of these created via this class..

Comment: So just make Computer Objects and add what ever lists you want to it and put the computer object back into Computers list .

Comment: something like this : `Computer c=new Computer("Apple");` ...next how to add a list that only "Apple" can have access..
i dont want to have `List<String>` element in my constructor...

Comment: See above class ...some lines of code is there before this line ...Pass the list of printers also..While creating ..

Comment: i DONT WANNA HAVE `List<String>` IN MY CONSTRUCTOR !!!
i sholud be able to add more printers later on..

Comment: ok..remove it from constructor and then  get the list of customer and add it

Comment: CUSTOMERS ??
can you show it...i pressume you are trying to say use getters and setters ...